# Количество выводимых новостей WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет. Столкнулся с необходимостью ограничить числом количество выводимых новостей.
На данный момент стоит такой код

```
<?php $param = ''; $orderby = 'DESC'; $sdate = array('20161201', date('ymd',  strtotime('-2 day'))); include('includes/server.php'); ?>
```

Нужно поправить код что бы отображалось не более 40 новостей. Буду бесконечно благодарен за помощь

Comment: В этом коде поправлять нечего - он не имеет никакого отношения к ВП. А кол-во постов (а не новостей) настраивается в админке.

Comment: Спасибо за коммент но решает) 
Уже разобрался 

Просто добавляем $countItems = 100;   Вместо 100 любое значение

Comment: Если это что-то "решает", то "это" не имеет отношения к ВП. Более того такая хрень  опасна для существования CMS.